# Where to look for 'cert' and 'key' to create https server?

Tags: node.js, express, https, secret-key

I am trying to move my websocket server to wss, because github pages require https certificate, and to do so, I need to:

```
const server = https.createServer({
  cert: fs.readFileSync('/path/to/cert.pem'),
  key: fs.readFileSync('/path/to/key.pem')
});
const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ server });
```

My question is: where do I get this cert and key?
I don't know anything about how https works, to be honest, just looking for advice here.
By the way, I am using express, so I need to cope with it somehow. Currently the server in the localhost test, but It usually runs on aws linux ami

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an https certificate with the accompanying key to run any https server. Use [LetsEncrypt.com](https://letsencrypt.org/) to get them.  The LetsEncrypt site offers instructions about that. There are tutorials on the internet about how to do it, and an [npm package called Greenlock](https://www.npmjs.com/package/greenlock) to help you automate it.  For LetsEncrypt to work, you need to be able to prove you control the domain in question, by putting some secret token string in your DNS or on your http version of your web site.

Or, if you work for an org that already has a certificate for its public web server, you can ask the person who runs that server to buy you a certificate from whatever Certificate Authority your org uses.

When you stand up a machine to run any sort of node-based https server, you ordinarily create a directory somewhere to hold your secrets. Your certificate and private key are such secrets.

You might use a directory named `/usr/local/secrets` for this purpose, and place your cert and key files there. It's also good for files that store various API keys and other secret stuff needed by your server.

So your code would say

```
const server = https.createServer({
  cert: fs.readFileSync('/usr/local/secrets/cert.pem'),
  key: fs.readFileSync('/usr/local/secrets/key.pem')
});
const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ server });
```

Don't commit your secrets to git or any other source control system. Always put them outside your application's directory hierarchy. Or they won't stay secret. You really don't want your https cert and key floating around the intertoobz.

Comment: That is not answering my question about how to generate it, or where to find

Comment: I added some advice here about getting certs.